# Postgres :hstore and first_or_create

Tags: postgresql, hstore, ruby-on-rails-4.1

I'm using Single Table Inheritance using `:hstore` as outlined here: http://www.devmynd.com/blog/2013-3-single-table-inheritance-hstore-lovely-combination (basically, all attributes of the inheriting model is stored inside a :hstore table)

Suppose I have a class Person that inherits Entity, and that the name of the `:hstore` table containing information relevant to a Person is called 'info'. The following works fine:

```
Person.create(name: 'TestUser', info: {"gender" => "male"})
```

But the following fails:

```
Person.where(name: 'TestUser', info: {"gender" => "male"}).first_or_create
```

The failure is caused by the following SQL statement

```
 SELECT "parties".* FROM "parties"  WHERE "parties"."type" IN ('Person') AND "parties"."name" = 'Daniel' AND "information"."gender" = 'male'
```

with the error being

```
missing FROM-clause entry for table "info"
```

Anybody knows if there's a fix for this? Is there another method that I should be using? Right now I'm using find and then create separately, which is fine (just a few more lines to write).

Thanks!